# How to remove duplicate masters in Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture, file-management

There are many photos in my Aperture library that have two masters, each one jpeg and one raw. I'd like to delete one of both, but I didn't even found a way of splitting them.

Comment: ["The short answer is that you don't."](http://archive.bagelturf.com/aparticles/library/deljpeg/index.php)

Comment: Is it before or after you have made any editing of the pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a smart folder? Set file type to RAW, and then you can delete the files. Its however not ideal.

Comment: Not completely the solution I hoped for, but certainly better than nothing.

Comment: yeah i know :( i just switched of jpegs, so either i shoot RAW or JPEG....Depending on your camera you can also choose to store small JPEG + RAW.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting version or delete master and all versions, however, back up the photos you want to keep first.